# c++ easiest way to multiply multi-dimensional vector by scalar

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm doing montecarlo simulation on **c++**.
To keep the property of normal distribution which mean is **0**, I want to multiply random vectors by **-1**.

For example, If I have two random numbers **( -1.4, +0.3 )** which were generated by random generator, I want to add **(+1.4, -0.3)** on random numbers. So I can get **(-1.4, 0.3, 1.4, 0.3)** at my random number vectors.

I want to expand this to multi-dimensional vector. Random numbers should be generated by simulation number and period number. So random number vector should be multi-dimensional.

In case of **1-d** case, I know that I can use transform.
I want to know how to use transform in **2-d** case. if there are any other better way, I want to know also.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "mulitidimensional vector"?  What does it mean "random numbers should be generated by simulation number and period number"?  What do you want to achieve? It is not clear what do you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to use Eigen library to perform mathematical operations on matrix, vectors,... This library is very powerful!

> (Eigen is a C++ template library for linear algebra: matrices,
>   vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms.)
>
> Eigen offers matrix/vector arithmetic operations either through
>   overloads of common C++ arithmetic operators such as +, -, *, or
>   through special methods such as dot(), cross(), etc. For the Matrix
>   class (matrices and vectors), operators are only overloaded to support
>   linear-algebraic operations. For example, matrix1 * matrix2 means
>   matrix-matrix product, and vector + scalar is just not allowed. If you
>   want to perform all kinds of array operations, not linear algebra, see
>   the next page.

[Eigen tutorial](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html)